# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<form id=""... is not valid JSON In WooCommerce payment gateway

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm working on a payment plugin for WooCommerce. The payment gateway manual says that I need to submit form with data using the POST method to redirect customer to the 3DS confirmation page. I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<form id=""... is not valid JSON.

Whole code https://codeshare.io/Odwv4N.

Piece of code in which the form is submitted:

```
$json = json_encode($data);

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.pinpaygate.com/dev/card/process',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$json,
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            $response_data = json_decode($response, true);

            // Check if success field is true
            if ($response_data['success'] == true) {
                // Check if 3DSecure authentication is needed
                if (isset($response_data['acs'])) {
                    // If the acs object contains multiple fields, perform a POST redirection
                    if (isset($response_data['acs']['parameters']['PaReq'])) {
                         // Perform a POST redirection using a form
                        echo '<form id="myForm" action="' . $response_data['acs']['url'] . '" method="POST">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="' . $response_data['acs']['parameters']['PaReq'] . '">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="MD" value="' . $response_data['acs']['parameters']['MD'] . '">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="' . $response_data['acs']['parameters']['TermUrl'] . '">';
                        echo '</form>';
                        echo '<script>document.getElementById("myForm").submit();</script>';
                        exit;
```

I have already disabled all third party plugins and used Storefront theme to eliminate their influence. I tried to make a request using my code directly without WooCommerce and I was redirected to the 3DS page as expected.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I'm also facing it.